# SmartGWT and Selenium : How to perform selenium test on SmartGWT's DynamicForm elements?

Tags: java, gwt, selenium, smartgwt

I am new to Selenium along with GWT and SmartGWT component.

I am not able to find out way to test SmartGWT's DynamicForms components like TextItem, SelectItem etc. These components are composites and do not have methods to set identifier attribute.

Kindly guide me how to test the DynamicForm using Selenium.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

SmartGWT has extensive built-in support for Selenium.  Read about it here:

http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwtee-latest/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/docs/UsingSelenium.html

Do not attempt to set your own DOM identifiers.  This is unnecessary, and is the wrong approach.